# Mysql - Get count of zeros (0) in each column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 53 columns (all integer types) and thousands of rows. I just want to be able to figure out how many times does a zero occur in each column . So the example output would be something like below :

```
Columns | Zero Counts

col1        2
col2        3
col3        2 
col4        0
```

I've tried different queries though none fit in right . Would appreciate any help .

Comment: use Union for that

Comment: could you elaborate please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68078865/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this should work:

```
select 'col1', Count(*) from yourtable where col1=0
Union 
select 'col2', Count(*) from yourtable where col2=0
Union 
select 'col3', Count(*) from yourtable where col3=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.
SELECT count(`col1`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `col1`=0
UNION
SELECT count(`col2`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `col2`=0