# Given a list, how to get the count from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a string list, I want to get the count of each item from the table. However, I don't know how to get the count(0) of item which does not exist in the table.

for example, I have a table as follow.

```
id   name      score
------------------------
1    aaa       10
2    ccc       20
3    aaa       10
4    ddd       15
```

Given a list ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] , I hope a query can return me a result like

```
aaa 2
bbb 0
ccc 1
```

I tried "select name, count(*) from table where name in ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc") group by name;", but the result is without the count of "bbb". Can I do it in a single query?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (e.g. missing data) in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values list must be a rowsource, not a criteria in WHERE.

```sql
SELECT criteria.name, COUNT(table.score)
FROM ( SELECT 'aaa' name UNION ALL
       SELECT 'bbb'      UNION ALL
       SELECT 'ccc' ) criteria
LEFT JOIN table USING (name)
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you got your appropriate answer I am sharing here another way of doing it using `JSON_TABLE()`

```
 create table yourtable( id int,   name varchar(10),      score int);
 insert into yourtable values(1,    'aaa',       10),
 (2    ,'ccc',       20),
 (3    ,'aaa',      10),
 (4    ,'ddd',       15);
```

Query:

```
 SELECT value name, count(name) name_count
      FROM
        JSON_TABLE(
          '["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]',
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
            Value varchar(50) PATH "$"
          )
        ) data left join yourtable on value=name
        group by value;
```

Output:

| name | name_count |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 2 |
| bbb | 0 |
| ccc | 1 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=446c05eb8e62614fcddf521d2bd8e13a)*